# Fetching ElementCollecion from Hibernate based on a condition

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql

I have a class named `User` and it has a element collection `groups` like below:

```
public class User {

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_groups", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
    private Set<String> groups;

    //Other fields
}
```

Now I need to fetch list of users, based on group name. The query is something like this:

```
@Query("select distinct user from User user " +
        "left join fetch user.groups groups " +
        "where :groupName IN groups")
List<User> findUsersByGroupName(@Param("groupName") String groupName);
```

This works fine but in the fetched `User` objects, I am getting only one group(which I am passing). I need all the groups of a `User` in the fetched objects. How can I do that efficiently?
I have tried using `elements` and `member of` but as I have many users, it is taking lot of time(in minutes) to execute the query.

Comment: What database do you use? I am afraid,  to make this query efficient and fitting you needs you should write a sql native query for this.

Comment: @SternK Thanks for your response. I am using Postgres. I have fixed the above issue by removing the fetch keyword and initialized the collection after getting the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the above query is `fetch` keyword which fetches the data eagerly from the database so only one group was there. I have removed the `fetch` keyword and initialized the groups after fetching `User`. This gives all the groups of a user.